# A better way to extract data in Python

Tags: python

I have some code that gets the lecture times from online courses I take. The resulting answer is in the form of `[['02:29']]`. I think I'd use the following code to get the number out:

```
time1=timeList[0]
time2=time1[0]
time3=(time2.contents[0])
(parts) = time3.split(":")
```

Is there a better way to do this in fewer steps? And what resources are there to help me in the future? Or is this one of those things you just learn by coding and then asking for help?

Comment: The first question might get answers. The others are asking references for tools and they're not allowed.

Comment: So you just want the numbers out? How much would the format of your text change?

Comment: What does "`[['02:29']]`" mean exactly? Why `.contents`? What type is `timeList`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Itertool is always available:

[Itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html%20itertools)

And you can chain your list considering it's always in the same format:

```
import itertools
time1 = list(itertools.chain(*timeList))[0].split(":")[0]
```

This solution is very fast and it works very smooth. A bit complicated to understand but it makes the work very efficiently.

- Note: it also works with more levels of subarrays, no matter if you have 1, 2 or 3 levels

**Update**

Due to you indicated you want to convert it to raw seconds the answer is:

```
time1 = list(itertools.chain(*timeList))[0].split(":")
seconds_total = (time1[0] * 60) + time1[1]
```

Comment: Sorry for not formatting this right: My goal was to get [[02:20]] to 02:20 so then I could then run that number against code to convert it from min:sec to plain seconds. Then I can add up all the raw seconds and reconvert them later. HTH?

Comment: It's easy, take time1 like the split only and you can add up time1[0] * 60 + time1[1]

Comment: Max: Thanks for the update. That works!!

Comment: Your welcome, the question wasn't clear at the beginning that's why many of us were hitting around the bushes.

Answer (score 1):

Is it a list in a list with just one item?

Then you could achieve the same with:

```
test = [['02:29']]
parts = test[0][0].split(':')
print parts # result: ['02', '29']
```

But I'am not sure if I got you right